# Apply OData function on retrieved data in a query

Tags: function, odata, asp.net-core-odata

I just started to work with Odata and I had an impression the OData querying is kind of flexible.

But in some cases I want to retrieve updated/newly calculated data on the fly. In my case this data is SalaryData values. At some point, I want them to be slightly tweaked with additional applied calculation function. And the critical point that this action must occur  on the retrieval of the data with the general request query.

But I don't know, is that applicable to use function in this case?
Ideally, I want to have the similar request:

**/odata/Employee(1111)?$expand=SalaryData/CalculculationFunction(40)**

Here I want to apply CalculculationFunction with parameters on SalaryData.
Is that possible to do it in OData in this way? Or should I create an entity set of salary data and retrieve calculated data directly using the query something like

**/odata/SalaryData(1111)/CalculculationFunction(40)**
But this way is least preferable for me, because I don't want to use id of SalaryData in request

Current example of the function I created:

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 10, MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 10)]
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("({key})/FloatingWindow(days={days})")]
public SingleResult<Models.SalaryData> MovingWindow([FromODataUri] Guid key, [FromODataUri] int days)
{
    if (days <= 0)
        return new SingleResult<Models.SalaryData>(Array.Empty<Models.SalaryData>().AsQueryable());
    var cachedSalaryData = GetAllowedSalaryData().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(key));
    var mappedSalaryData = mapper.Map<Models.SalaryData>(cachedSalaryData);
    mappedSalaryData = Models.SalaryData.FloatingWindowAggregation(days, mappedSalaryData);
    var salaryDataResult = new[] { mappedSalaryData };
    return new SingleResult<Models.SalaryData>(salaryDataResult.AsQueryable());
}
```

Comment: Why not just make a custom function on the Employee controller to return the updated data, you don't have to go to all this effort, the function can even return a unique model if you want, in the same way that you can have contained entities I guess...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually, the main requirement is to apply it particularly on SalaryData entity and use it in usual Odata query syntax. Well, that's because we have some complex relations among entities and it might be not only Employee entity which contains this Salary data., but the others too.  So, if it's possible to use functions on query expansions, that would be really rad

Comment: What framework version are you using?

Comment: Showing the `CalculculationFunction` implementation would help to identify the OData feature that could be used to approximate the same behaviour

Comment: It's .NET Framework 4.7.2 and we're using OData v.4

Comment: I added an example of the function I created. But it's set inside SalaryData controller

Comment: I will try hard not to comment on the use of AutoMapper inside your OData Implementation... You have added a 3rd layer of ORM, this level of abstraction contributes to some common performance issues, in most cases the Edm Model replaces the need for AutoMapper. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is always an overlap between *What is OData Compliant Routing* vs *What can I do with Routes in Web API*. It is not always necessary to conform to the OData (V4) specification, but a non-conforming route will need custom logic on the client as well.

The common workaround for this type of request is to create `Function` endpoint bound to the `Employee` item that accepts the parameter input that will be used to materialize the data. The URL might look like this instead:

```
/odata/Employee(1111)/WithCalculatedSalary(40)?$expand=SalaryData
```

This method could then internally call the existing `MovingWindow` function from the `SalaryDataController` to build the results. You could also engineer both functions to call a common set based routine.

The reason that you you should bind this function to the `EmployeeController` is that the primary identifying resource that correlates the resulting data together is the *Employee*.

In this way OData v4 compliant clients would still be able to execute this function and importantly would be able to discover it without any need for customisations.

If you didn't need to return the `Employee` resource as part of the response then you could still serve a collection of `SalaryData` from the `EmployeeController`:

```
/odata/Employee(1111)/CalculatedSalary(days=40)
```

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 10, MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 10)]
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("({key})/FloatingWindow(days={days})")]
public IQueryable<Models.SalaryData> CalculatedSalary([FromODataUri] int key, [FromODataUri] int days)
{
    ...
}
```

```
builder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employee")
       .EntityType
       .Function("CalculatedSalary")  
       .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<SalaryData>("SalaryData")
       .Parameter<int>("days");
```

### [$compute and $search in ASP.NET Core OData 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/compute-and-search-in-asp-net-core-odata-8/)

The OData v4.01 specification does have support for [System Query Option $compute](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_SystemQueryOptioncompute) which was designed to enable clients to append computed values into the response structure, you could hijack this pipeline and define your own *function* that can be executed from a `$compute` clause, but the expectation is that system canonical functions are used with a combination of literal values and field references.

> The ASP.Net implementation has only introduced support for this in the OData Lib v8 runtime, as yet I have not yet found a good example of how to implement custom functions, but syntactically it is feasible.
>
> The same concept could be used to augment the `$apply` execution, if this calculation operates over a collection and effectively performs an *aggregate* evaluation, then `$apply`

It might be that your current `CalculculationFunction` can be translated directly into a `$compute` statement, otherwise if you promote some of the calculation steps (metadata) as columns in the schema (you might use SQL Computed Columns for this...) then `$compute` could be a viable option.